# Re-weight with WeightIt

Tags: r, weighted, imbalanced-data, propensity-score-matching

I weighted my population using WeightIt package

```
library(WeightIt)
library(cobalt)
data("lalonde", package = "cobalt")

W.out <- weightit(treat ~ age + married + race,
                  data = lalonde, estimand = "ATE", method = "ps")
bal.tab(W.out, threshold=0.1)
```

In this case, age is not balanced and I want to perform IPTW again to balance the population.
How can I re-weight? I don't know what code to write

Comment: What do you mean by re-weight? Estimate an entirely new set of weights, or estimate a set of weights to be combined with the current weights somehow?

Comment: @Noah What I want to do is achieve a complete balance in my covariates. When using IPTW, the balance is not achieved as age has a SD>10%. Therefore, I would like to re-perform IPTW on the already weighted population in order to achieve balance.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do that instead of estimating a single set of weights that does achieve balance. Just use entropy balancing or something similar on the original dataset. Why retain the poorly performing weights you just estimated?

Comment: @Noah I understand what you mean, however my research group decided to stick with IPTW. Therefore, I need to find a way to achieve balance with IPTW.

Comment: @Noah is there a way to re-weight after performing the first IPTW in order to achieve balance?

Comment: If your IPTW didn't achieve balance, why don't you try a different model specification? Why do you think you can or need to "re-weight" instead of just trying a different set of weights? What if you use CBPS, which is just a regular logistic regression IPTW but has better balance properties? If you want me to tell your research group that they're wrong for demanding to use a poorly performing method, I can do that for you.

Comment: @Noah Thank you, you are really kind! However for now I would like just to "re-weight", I will try to convince to use other methods later on.

Comment: But that method doesn't exist. There is no application of that in the literature and no justification for it. So you are requesting an experimental method far less studied than the other methods I'm proposing. Where did you hear of such an idea? Why do you think this method will be more palatable to your research team and to reviewers when it has never appeared in the literature before?

Comment: @Noah I thought that re-weighting was possible because when I read about "multiple attempts to estimate weights to achieve balance" I though that you can perform IPTW again and again to achieve balance. So, when IPTW doesn't work and there is imbalance, the solution is to change the method I use to balance the covariates?

Comment: @Noah Moreover, you are truly great in this. Can you suggest me some books or sources  from which I can learn and become progressively better? Unfortunately a strict statistical language is not the best for me as I am not a statistician.

Comment: Ah yes, best practice recommends re-specifying different weight models to try to find the single set of weights that achieves balance. It is not a process of refining existing weights to achieve balance. So you must estimate a whole new set of weights and keep doing that until you achieve satisfactory balance. If you don't want to spend a lot of time doing that, use entropy balancing, which is available in `WeightIt` and always yields good balance.

Comment: @Noah But I assume that "So you must estimate a whole new set of weights and keep doing that until you achieve satisfactory balance." is not done through IPTW if it fails the first time but with different methods, right?

Comment: No, you can use IPTW but trying a different model (e.g., adding squared terms or interactions or using machine learning methods like GBM or BART instead of logistic regression). Entropy balancing and all other methods available in `WeightIt` are forms of IPTW, though. The main `WeightIt` [vignette](https://ngreifer.github.io/WeightIt/articles/WeightIt.html) gives an example of trying one specification and moving on to a different one when the first one doesn't yield satisfactory balance.